# Excel formatting numbers

Tags: c#, excel, number-formatting

I'm looking to get the following result below.

3 → 3

9.1 → 9.1

5.67 → 5.67

0 → 0

I'm using the following number formatting below. It's working fine except 3 -> 3.
/ 0 -> 0. etc

```
ws.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "###,##0.##";
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Which library are you using to interact with Excel? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: I'm currently using OfficeOpenXML

Comment: I'm confused by your samples. Do you want an arrow in the format? Other than that I don't see why you can't just use the General format. That will show the numbers with or without decimals, as required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no format in Excel that will omit decimals for whole numbers and show only two decimals for non-integers.

You are using a number format that always contains a decimal point and will show  up to two decimals. If you don't want to show decimals for whole numbers, then just use the Excel default format, i.e. don't format the cell, or format it as "General".

If you want to ensure that numbers with more than two decimals only show two decimals in the General format, you need to round the number first to have just the desired number of decimals.